# SQL execution plan:there's a index on column but it use 'table access full' in hash join

Tags: oracle, performance

The information of "table access full" appears in the SQL execution plan of a SQL statement.

I want to know why it does not use index.

Or is there any other optimizations?

**After checking ,I get the info:**

1. “table access full” appeared in hash join.
2. Columns of two tables in hash join have the same type.
3. DB version 10.2.0.3.
4. The column in "table access full" has index.
5. The last collection of tables and index statistics was dated June
   12th.
6. When I run a single table queries on the column, the index is used.

**Details:**

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  5wz1z56666666, child number 13
--------------------------------------
SELECT count(Id) num FROM ccshare.blue WHERE  id in (select id from(select
a.*,b.documentid,b.variablename,b.variablecname,b.variablevalue  from  ccshare.blue
a,ccshare.blueEx b where    a.id= b.documentid   and     a.formid= :1  and
a.MdlId= :2  and     (a.tflag= :3 or a.tflag is null)  and     (a.overflag =
:4 or a.overflag = 0)  and     (a.pages <> :5 and a.pages <> 9)  and     a.subject like :6)
cc    group by id  having count(id)>= 0) AND ((hisuserids like :7  or curuserids like :8 or
curuserids1 like :9 or curuserids2 like :10) and (hisdeluserids not like :11 or hisdeluserids
is null)) AND (tflag= :12 or tflag is null) AND formid> :13


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1599999999

----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                |       |       |       | 45356 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE               |                |     1 |   344 |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                |  1410 |   473K|       | 45356   (2)| 00:09:05 |
|   3 |    VIEW                       | VW_NSO_1       |  1410 | 18330 |       | 43937   (2)| 00:08:48 |
|*  4 |     FILTER                    |                |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      HASH GROUP BY            |                |  1410 |   103K|       | 43937   (2)| 00:08:48 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN               |                |   405K|    29M|  2232K| 43903   (2)| 00:08:47 |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL      | blue          | 28186 |  1899K|       | 11964   (2)| 00:02:24 |
|   8 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | blueEX_DOCUID |    15M|    87M|       | 18550   (2)| 00:03:43 |
|*  9 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| blue          |     1 |   331 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | blue_KEY      |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$09D7319C

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------
   3 - SEL$833EDA65 / VW_NSO_1@SEL$09D7319C
   4 - SEL$833EDA65
   7 - SEL$833EDA65 / a@SEL$3
   8 - SEL$833EDA65 / b@SEL$3
   9 - SEL$09D7319C / blue@SEL$1
  10 - SEL$09D7319C / blue@SEL$1

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('10.2.0.3')
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$833EDA65")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$09D7319C")
      UNNEST(@"SEL$335DD26A")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$335DD26A")
      MERGE(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$833EDA65")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")
      NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$09D7319C" "VW_NSO_1"@"SEL$09D7319C")
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$09D7319C" "blue"@"SEL$1" ("blue"."ID"))
      LEADING(@"SEL$09D7319C" "VW_NSO_1"@"SEL$09D7319C" "blue"@"SEL$1")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$09D7319C" "blue"@"SEL$1")
      FULL(@"SEL$833EDA65" "a"@"SEL$3")
      INDEX_FFS(@"SEL$833EDA65" "b"@"SEL$3" ("blueEX"."DOCUMENTID"))
      LEADING(@"SEL$833EDA65" "a"@"SEL$3" "b"@"SEL$3")
      USE_HASH(@"SEL$833EDA65" "b"@"SEL$3")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

Peeked Binds (identified by position):
--------------------------------------

   1 - :1 (NUMBER): 107889
   2 - :2 (NUMBER): 188
   3 - :3 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): (null)
   4 - :4 (NUMBER): -1
   5 - :5 (NUMBER): 7
   6 - :6 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%he has a pretty dog%'

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   7 - :7 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%,4026722,%'
   8 - :8 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%,4026722*,%'
   9 - :9 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%,4026722*,%'
  10 - :10 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%,4026722*,%'
  11 - :11 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): '%,4026722,%'
  12 - :12 (VARCHAR2(30), CSID=852): (null)
  13 - :13 (NUMBER): 0

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   4 - filter(COUNT(*)>=0)
   6 - access("a"."ID"="b"."DOCUMENTID")
   7 - filter(("a"."SUBJECT" LIKE :6 AND "a"."FORMID"=:1 AND "a"."MDLID"=:2 AND
              "a"."PAGES"<>:5 AND "a"."PAGES"<>9 AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION("a"."OVERFLAG") AND
              ("a"."tflag" IS NULL OR "a"."tflag"=:3)))
   9 - filter((("HISUSERIDS" LIKE :7 OR "CURUSERIDS" LIKE :8 OR "CURUSERIDS1" LIKE :9 OR
              "CURUSERIDS2" LIKE :10) AND "FORMID">:13 AND ("HISDELUSERIDS" IS NULL OR "HISDELUSERIDS" NOT
              LIKE :11) AND ("tflag" IS NULL OR "tflag"=:12)))
  10 - access("ID"="$nso_col_1")

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) COUNT(*)[22]
   3 - "$nso_col_1"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "a"."ID"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "a"."ID"[NUMBER,22], COUNT(*)[22]
   6 - (#keys=1) "a"."ID"[NUMBER,22]
   7 - "a"."ID"[NUMBER,22]
   8 - "b"."DOCUMENTID"[NUMBER,22]
  10 - "blue".ROWID[ROWID,10]




SQL> explain plan for select count(id) from ccshare.blue;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 302********

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name           | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                |     1 |   890   (2)| 00:00:11 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |                |     1 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| blue_OVERFLAG |  1155K|   890   (2)| 00:00:11 |
```

**10046 event info (tkprof) of the SQL:**

```
TKPROF: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Thu Jun 21 22:48:56 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Trace file: /opt/app/oracle/admin/testdb/udump/testdb1_ora_7668044.trc
Sort options: default

********************************************************************************
count    = number of times OCI procedure was executed
cpu      = cpu time in seconds executing 
elapsed  = elapsed time in seconds executing
disk     = number of physical reads of buffers from disk
query    = number of buffers gotten for consistent read
current  = number of buffers gotten in current mode (usually for update)
rows     = number of rows processed by the fetch or execute call
********************************************************************************



call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.01       0.01          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2      6.67      16.00        163     139223          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4      6.68      16.02        163     139223          0           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: SYS

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      1  SORT AGGREGATE (cr=139223 pr=163 pw=0 time=16007522 us)
      0   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=139223 pr=163 pw=0 time=16007499 us)
      2    VIEW  VW_NSO_1 (cr=139215 pr=163 pw=0 time=16005404 us)
      2     FILTER  (cr=139215 pr=163 pw=0 time=16005400 us)
      2      HASH GROUP BY (cr=139215 pr=163 pw=0 time=16005391 us)
     32       HASH JOIN  (cr=139215 pr=163 pw=0 time=15614187 us)
      2        TABLE ACCESS FULL blue (cr=53972 pr=0 pw=0 time=1725549 us)
15511417        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN blueEX_DOCUID (cr=85243 pr=163 pw=0 time=15516352 us)(object id 60473)
      0    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GREEN (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=1964 us)
      2     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN blue_KEY (cr=6 pr=0 pw=0 time=961 us)(object id 60454)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  library cache lock                              1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message to client                       2        0.00          0.00
  gc current block 2-way                       1645        0.00          0.62
  db file sequential read                        23        0.00          0.01
  db file parallel read                           8        0.00          0.00
  gc cr multi block request                   50254        0.00          7.45
  db file scattered read                         29        0.00          0.02
  SQL*Net message from client                     2       13.69         13.69



********************************************************************************

OVERALL TOTALS FOR ALL NON-RECURSIVE STATEMENTS

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.01       0.01          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2      6.67      16.00        163     139223          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4      6.68      16.02        163     139223          0           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1

Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                       4        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message from client                     4       19.75         39.08
  library cache lock                              1        0.00          0.00
  gc current block 2-way                       1645        0.00          0.62
  db file sequential read                        23        0.00          0.01
  db file parallel read                           8        0.00          0.00
  gc cr multi block request                   50254        0.00          7.45
  db file scattered read                         29        0.00          0.02


OVERALL TOTALS FOR ALL RECURSIVE STATEMENTS

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0

Misses in library cache during parse: 0

    1  user  SQL statements in session.
    0  internal SQL statements in session.
    1  SQL statements in session.
********************************************************************************
Trace file: /opt/app/oracle/admin/testdb/udump/testdb1_ora_7668044.trc
Trace file compatibility: 10.01.00
Sort options: default

       1  session in tracefile.
       1  user  SQL statements in trace file.
       0  internal SQL statements in trace file.
       1  SQL statements in trace file.
       1  unique SQL statements in trace file.
   52007  lines in trace file.
      16  elapsed seconds in trace file.
```

Comment: The optimiser seems to think that when joining `blue` with `blueex` in the inner query, it's more efficient to do a full table scan of `blue`, and then (using the IDs identified by those filters) an fast index scan of `blueex` - implying all four column used form that table are in the index? Do you have a reason to think that isn't the most efficient approach?

Comment: Full table scans or hash joins are not bad. If the cardinalities are right (28186 rows after applying all filters on your BLUE table), then a full table scans and hash join probably makes sense.
If your query returns a significantly smaller number of rows and you have an index that should be used, then we need to investigate why that index wasn't used. 
The fact that a "select count(id) from ccshare.blue" uses an index is unrelated.
My advice is to gather plan statistics for an execution of this query to see the actual number of rows flowing through each step and the actual elapsed time.

Comment: @AlexPoole,thanks for your reply,I just guess that if there is an index on this column, it may be more efficient than the full table scan in hash join.There is a valid index on that column.

Comment: @RobvanWijk,thanks.I have gathered the 10046 event and tkprof.trc,and have updated the "Details" above.

Comment: That's useful extra info. Now we see that the optimizer thinks selecting the rows from the blue table yields 28186 rows, but there are actually only 2. So using a suitable index could definitely improve your query. You have lots of filters on the blue table. Do you know which filters are most selective? And do you have an index on that/those columns? And are there histograms on that/those columns?

Comment: @RobvanWijk
1.I don't know which filters are most selective,the developer of this APP come from another company.
2.Columns in 'TABLE ACCESS FULL blue' and 'INDEX FAST FULL SCAN blueEX_DOCUID' have indexes.
3.I will check if there is histogram on those columns.

Comment: @RobvanWijk ' the optimizer thinks selecting the rows from the blue table yields 28186 rows, but there are actually only 2.' , How do you analyze and confirm, can you teach me?

Comment: @RobvanWijk The id columns of the two tables(blue and blueex) don't have histograms.

Comment: The TABLE ACCESS FULL line of table BLUE says 28186 in the Rows column of your explain plan. The same line says 2 Rows in your tkprof output. Histograms on ID columns are not particularly useful here: they are unique values. You do want histograms on your skewed columns used in your filters. You don't need someone else for that, just query the blue table with each one of your filters to find out which one is most selective.

Comment: @RobvanWijk OK，thanks very much for your kind help.